# Wordpress - ACF - Validation getting removed on update

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

In my current website I have installed ACF-PRO plugin to create custom forms.

Now I have allowed plugin auto update for in my development environment. So whenever plugin gets updated, it resets the previously set validations. Is this a normal or issue?

Current installed version is ACF-PRO - 6.2.5